# How can I make my code work everyday automatically on PL/SQL?

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql

I need to find the growth trend of data in my PL/SQL Database. There is a data dictionary view called `dba_segments` and I need to get data size information from it, and basically I need to collect this data in the same table everyday. (with date included) I have started learning SQL only last month so I don't know how to do it. My code now compiles but does not actually collect the data inside.

```
CREATE TABLE timeDate (
   id INT,
  ts TIMESTAMP DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
);

CREATE TABLE add_data_growth AS
SELECT DATE(`ts`) FROM timedate WHERE id =someId
 SELECT segment_name, bytes/1024/1024 AS MB FROM dba_segments;

CREATE PROCEDURE collect_sizes
AS
BEGIN
INSERT INTO data_growth select trunc(sysdate), dba_segments.*
from dba_segments;
insert into data_growth
end add_data_growth;
```

`dba_segments` is the source to collect size information, the rest of the tables are what I have created myself to store the collected data. 
I need to collect size information of segments everyday, with date included.
How can I make this code work every day, for example twice a day?

Comment: welcome to SO, please edit your question and use "code sample" for greater readability.

Comment: You seem to be confused about the table structure of `add_data_growth`. At one place you're creating only 3 columns. But, in your insert you are inserting all the columns. First, decide the table design you're intending to use.Also, what is `timeDate` table used for? Your procedure code does **not** compile, it has syntax errors. Clear up things for us if you wish us to help you.

Comment: Have a look at `dbms_scheduler` concept, especially on this site. You need to refresh your statistics to get the current state everytime prior to running this scheduler by analyzing whole schemas of your DB. Otherwise, the stale data statistics are brought through `dba_segments`.

Comment: @BarbarosÖzhan DBA_SEGMENTS is not maintained by dbms_stats. You may be thinking of blocks, num_rows etc in DBA_TABLES.

Comment: @oo08 You don’t have a PL/SQL Database, you have an Oracle database. PL/SQL is the programming language used for writing procedures etc

Comment: As you said I considered like `dba_tables`. Thank you @WilliamRobertson.

Answer (score 1):

Hope this might be helpful. Also go through this link (http://www.dba-oracle.com/t_table_growth_reports.htm)

```
--First create a sequence 
CREATE SEQUENCE  IDS_AUTOINC START WITH 100 INCREMENT BY  1 ;
```

Then create a table, consolidated your required tables, assuming you need an ID, timestamp, segment_name and bytes column from dba_segments view.

```
Create table data_growth
as 
select IDS_AUTOINC.nextval as ID, SYSTIMESTAMP as ts, 
dba_segments.segment_name,bytes/1024/1024 AS MB  from dba_segments;
```

If you just need to insert data into the data_growth table twice a day, I think we really doesn't need a procedure an block can do the job.

```
    BEGIN
      DBMS_SCHEDULER.create_job (
        job_name        => 'Daily_dba_segments_Cal',
        job_type        => 'PLSQL_BLOCK',
        job_action      => 'BEGIN INSERT into data_growth select IDS_AUTOINC.nextval as ID, SYSTIMESTAMP as ts, 
                            dba_segments.segment_name,bytes/1024/1024 AS MB  from dba_segments;commit; END;',
        start_date      => SYSTIMESTAMP,
        repeat_interval => 'freq=hourly;INTERVAL=12',
        enabled         => TRUE);
    END;
```

To Validate

```
    select trunc(TS),SEGMENT_NAME,max(MB)  from data_growth
    group by trunc(TS), SEGMENT_NAME, MB
    having MB=(select max(MB) from data_growth) ;
```

Useful links:
https://blogs.oracle.com/academy/free-online-beginners-tutorial-for-sql

Comment: Thank you! The link is very very helpful too